# Adding alternate login doesn't work

Tags: support, login, user-accounts

I have been trying to add an Gmail login to this account for quite some time now. But irrespective of what I did, the alternate login doesn't get added.

1. I tried adding email id + password. It doesn't work.
2. I tried adding Gmail OAuth2. It shows an confirmation page, but it doesn't actually add that link.
3. At some point, it ended up creating two accounts. So I tried merging them, but the email for merging never arrived on Yahoo (current account email provider), despite multiple attempts. Currently, I have deleted the new account.

What should I do?

Comment: I think your best option is using the Contact link at the bottom of this page and have SE staff look at it. I can't imagine what else you could try and there is a chance any experiments cause more trouble.

Comment: @rene Yes. The support fixed the issue for me.